# Como importar dados do ACCESS para MYSQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Tenho um `db ACCESS` com muitas tabelas e muitos dados registrados, preciso importar essas `tables` para meu novo `db`em `MYSQL`. algúem sabe uma forma ? ou um tutorial pra seguir ?

Estou usando o MySQL-Front e o phpMyAdmin para fazer o gerenciamento.

Comment: Tenta esse programa http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

Comment: Funcionou perfeito @HugoLeonardo . Abraços.

Comment: Posso postar como resposta?

Comment: Opa, manda ver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa o [Access to MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/download/a2m/msa2mys_5_4_0_274.zip). Neste [link](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) tem um tutorial (em inglês) sobre como utilizar: bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize esse Software [Acess To MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php)

Introduction

Access to MySQL is a small program that will convert Microsoft Access Databases to MySQL.

```
>  Wizard interface.
>     Transfer data directly from one server to another.
>     Create a dump file.
>     Select tables to transfer.
>     Select fields to transfer.
>     Transfer password protected databases.
>     Supports both shared security and user-level security.
>     Optional transfer of indexes.
>     Optional transfer of records.
>     Optional transfer of default values in field definitions.
>     Identifies and transfers auto number field types.
>     Command line interface.
>     Easy install, uninstall and upgrade.
```